# Erro ao utilizar JavaMail com conta do Office365

Tags: java, javamail, microsoft-office

Tenho uma classe Java que funciona perfeitamente para enviar emails através de uma conta do Gmail. Porém, mesmo utilizando as configurações recomendadas para enviar um email por SMTP com o Office365, é retornado um erro.

O erro é o seguinte:

> exception javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

Segue abaixo o código da minha classe:

```
public class GmailBean {

    public static final String SERVIDOR_SMTP = "smtp.office365.com";
    public static final int PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP = 587;
    private static final String CONTA_PADRAO = "xxx@xxx.com";
    private static final String SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO = "xxx";

    private String de;
    private String para;

    private String assunto;
    private String mensagem;

    public void enviarEmail() throws MessagingException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        AutenticaUsuario autenticaUsuario = new AutenticaUsuario(GmailBean.CONTA_PADRAO, GmailBean.SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO);

        Session session = Session.getInstance(this.configuracaoEmail(), autenticaUsuario);

        // try{
        Transport envio = null;
        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session);
        email.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(this.para));
        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.de));
        email.setSubject(this.assunto);
        email.setContent(this.mensagem, "text/plain");
        email.setSentDate(new Date());
        envio = session.getTransport("smtp");
        envio.connect(GmailBean.SERVIDOR_SMTP, GmailBean.CONTA_PADRAO, GmailBean.SENHA_CONTA_PADRAO);
        email.saveChanges();
        envio.sendMessage(email, email.getAllRecipients());
        envio.close();

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Mensagem enviada com sucesso!"));

        /* }
        catch(AddressException ex)
        { Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Erro ao enviar mensagem "+ ex.getMessage());
        logger.info("Erro ao enviar mensagem _____________"+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        catch(MessagingException ex)
        {
        Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Erro ao enviar mensagem "+ ex.getMessage());
        logger.info("Erro ao enviar mensagem _____________"+ ex.getMessage());

        }*/
    }

    public Properties configuracaoEmail() {
        Properties config = new Properties();

        config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        config.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enabled", "true");
        config.put("mail.smtp.host", SERVIDOR_SMTP);
        config.put("mail.user", GmailBean.CONTA_PADRAO);
        config.put("mail.smtp.port", PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP);
        config.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", PORTA_SERVIDOR_SMTP);
        config.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        config.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        return config;
    }

    // getters and setters

    class AutenticaUsuario extends Authenticator {

        private String usuario;
        private String senha;

        public AutenticaUsuario(String usuario, String senha) {

            this.usuario = usuario;
            this.senha = senha;

        }

        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(this.usuario, this.senha);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Já tentou sem as informações de `socketFactory` e também utilizando `mail.smtp.starttls.enable` no lugar de `mail.smtp.starttls.enabled`?

Comment: Bruno César, modifiquei a propriedade sugerida e comentei as linhas que faziam referência a socketFactory. Mesmo assim ainda há erro ao enviar o e-mail. Haveria mais alguma outra configuração a fazer que seja específica para o Office365?

Comment: O erro é o mesmo? Se não, qual é? Outra coisa é verificar se o SMTP server não é SMTPS, daí você altera de `.smtp.` para `.smtps.` nas propriedades.

Comment: O erro é o seguinte: 
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

Comment: Logo mais posto um *gist* aqui e você testa para ver se funciona, por que não tenho nenhuma conta na office 365 para testar. Testei ontem num exemplo e o erro foi de autenticação, talvez funcione para você.

Comment: Veja se este [gist](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/12a529f7f752f2853b9f) lhe ajuda. Se não, me informe o erro quando usa ele.

Comment: Obrigado, Bruno César! Funcionou perfeitamente. Se quiser, crie uma resposta para que eu possa votar nela como correta.

Comment: OK, já incluo uma resposta para você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a mensagem:

> Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.office365.com, port: 587; nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

O problema é o uso de *SSL* para tráfego de uma mensagem em uma canal que não a reconhece. Por padrão o *SMTP* do Office 365 utiliza *TLS* [explicito](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Settings-for-POP-and-IMAP-access-for-Office-365-for-business-or-Microsoft-Exchange-accounts-7fc677eb-2491-4cbc-8153-8e7113525f6c#__toc383167843), ou seja, deve ser iniciado o *TLS* (a propriedade `mail.smtp.starttls.enable`) e não é necessário informações de *SSL*.

Então, algumas alterações a serem feitas:

- [alterar](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) de `mail.smtp.starttls.enabled` para `mail.smtp.starttls.enable`
- não habilite *SSL*, remova todas as propriedades que contenham `mail.smtp.socketFactory`, sendo que uma delas é um *SSL Socket Factory*

No final, as propriedades ficarão deste tipo:

```
config.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
config.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
config.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
config.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
```

Do resto, seu código está OK. Veja um exemplo completo neste [gist](https://gist.github.com/brunocribeiro/12a529f7f752f2853b9f).

**P.S.:** a [Comunidade Office 365](https://community.office365.com/) não está funcionando, lá existem algumas referência sobre a questão *SSL*/*TLS*. Assim que voltar atualizo esta resposta com mais detalhes.